# Переворот каждого слова в символьном массиве. C++

Tags: c++, char

Пример ввода - hello world
ПРимер вывода - olleh dlrow
Как это можно адекватно сделать?
Понимаю, как перевернуть массив, но последовательность слов при этом не сохраняется.

Comment: 1) Опеределить что такое "слово" 2) выделить слова в отдельные подмассивы 3) перевернуть каждый подмассив

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
void words(std::istream& input, std::ostream& out)
{
    char m[50];
    while  (input >> m) {
       std::reverse(m, m + strlen(m));
       out << m << ' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если слово это последовательность `isalpha`, то тогда

```
void flip_words(std::string& s) {
  auto it = s.begin(), last = s.end();
  auto isalpha = [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); };
  for (;;) {
    auto word_begin = std::find_if(first, last, isalpha);
    if (word_begin == last) return;
    it = std::find_if_not(word_begin, last, isalpha);
    std::reverse(word_begin, it);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string words(const std::string& line)
{
    std::stringstream in_words(line);
    std::stringstream out_words;
    std::string word;
    while  (in_words >> word) 
    {
       std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
       out_words << word << ' ';
    }

    return out_words.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while  (std::getline(std::cin, line)) 
    {
       std::cout << words(line) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
  string s;
  getline(cin, s);
  auto start = s.begin();
  for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if(s[i] == ' ' || i == s.size() - 1) {
      auto end = s.begin() + i;
      if(i == s.size() - 1) end++;
      reverse(start, end);
      end++;
      start = end;
    }
  }
  cout<<s;
  return 0;
}
```